# Modify NextJS 13.4 HTML Response for SSR Pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am exploring the potential use of NextJS 13.4 in an upcoming project, however I need to understand how I might be able to re-write part of the HTML on the response when requesting a page that has been server-side rendered.

We have an internal design system library that utilises the shadow-dom and needs to re-write the HTML that is being returned from the server so that when it arrives client-side, the clients device can continue to process it.

A barebones example of some JSX in a server component would look like this:

```
<text-component>Hello World</text-component>
```

When this page is requested, the response should have a swapped-out version of this that reads:

```
<text-component>
    <p class="text-component">Hello World</p>
</text-component>
```

We have a hydration function that takes care of swapping this in for us (inserting light DOM), as long as it can be supplied with the raw HTML to parse. This 'hydrated' HTML then needs returning to the client instead.

An example currently being explored for SSG pages would be to map over all the generated HTML files after the build process and run our hydration script, replacing the HTML files with the updates ones - just need a way of doing something similar to this for SSR pages.

Any help/advice would be great,
Cheers!